# ajaxComplete function "loader" running once

Tags: ajax

here is the code I'm using:

```
$(function() {
    $(".fav").click(function() {
        var page     = $('#page').attr('value');  
        var user     = $('#user').attr('value');
        var time     = $('#time').attr('value'); 
        var info = "page="+ page +"& user="+ user +"& time="+ time;
        $("#loading").html('<im g src="loader.gif" />');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "favorite.php",
            data: info, 
            success: function() {
                $("#loading").ajaxComplete(function(){}).slideUp();
                $('#fav').fadeOut(200).hide();
                $('#unfav').fadeIn(200).show();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    $(".unfav").click(function(){
        var page     = $('#page').attr('value');  
        var user     = $('#user').attr('value');
        var info = "page="+ page +"& user="+ user;
        $("#loading").html('<im g src="loader.gif" />');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "notfavorite.php",
            data: info, 
            success: function(){
                $("#loading").ajaxComplete(function(){}).slideUp();
                $('#unfav').fadeOut(200).hide();
                $('#fav').fadeIn(200).show();
            }
       });
       return false;
    });
});
```

Everything is working fine, it acts as a "like" "follow" button, the only problem is that the ajaxComplete() function only runs once.

Cheers!

Comment: Why are you attaching `ajaxComplete` listeners to things in the success function, the thing which is called... when the AJAX call completes?

Comment: should I be using ajaxstart() stop()?

Comment: The gif only appears the first time. Tried tweeking it but no joy..

Comment: Tried this no good either                                           beforeSend: 
function(){         
$("#loading").html('<img src="loader.gif" />');     
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $(".fav").click(function(){
    var page     = $('#page').attr('value');  
    var user     = $('#user').attr('value');
    var time     = $('#time').attr('value'); 
    var info = "page="+ page +"& user="+ user +"& time="+ time;        
    $("#loading").html('<im g src="loader.gif" />');
    $('#follow').hide();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "favorite.php",
      data: info, 
      success: function(){
        $('#loading').empty();
        $('#remove').fadeIn(200).show();
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
})();
```

same for .unfav